# Having issues with mathematical calculations and setprecision() function

Tags: c++, math, precision

I seem to be having a problem with a C++ coding question. It involves mathematical arithmetic and I seem to be getting all of my outputs correct except the final one. In addition to this, the decimal point format of my answers seem to be incorrect. The answers should contain two decimal places but only two out of my four decimal point answers seem to have two decimal places. When I try to use the precision() function, the answers go into scientific notation which I do not want.

Here is the question and answer: [image]

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    float principal;
    float interest_rate;
    float times_compounded;

    cout << "Hello, please enter a value for your principal: ";
    cin >> principal;
    cout << principal << endl;
    cout << "Please enter a value for your interest rate: ";
    cin >> interest_rate;
    cout << interest_rate << "%" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the number of times the interest is compounded during the year: ";
    cin >> times_compounded;
    cout << times_compounded << endl << endl;

    float interest = interest_rate * 10.197647;
    float amount = principal * pow((1 + (interest_rate/times_compounded)), times_compounded);

    cout << "Interest Rate: " << setw(19) << interest_rate << "%" << endl;
    cout << "Times Compounded: " << setw(17) << times_compounded << endl;
    cout << "Principal: " << setw(17) << "$ " << setw(7) << principal << endl;
    cout << "Interest: " << setw(20) << "$ " << interest << endl;
    cout << "Amount in Savings: " << setw(9) << "$ " << amount;

    return 0;
}
```

Here are my three inputs: 
1000, 4.25, 12

Any feedback would be appreciated, thank you for your time.

Comment: *Here are my three inputs: 1000, 4.25, 12* -- You could have [cut out almost half of the program you posted](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f14642926022466d) if you had just put those values directly in the variables.  There is no need for `cin` or input statements.

Comment: You need to use `setprecision()` to set the number of places, and `fixed` manipulator to stop formatting using scientific notation.

Comment: @Peter this solved one of my issues, thank you.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The question said that the program should ask for the principal, interest rate and number of times interest is compounded so I just assumed that I would need to use the cin statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the last value is wrong because you're using the interest rate as a normal number in the formula although it's actually a percentage. So you'd need to divide it by 100:

```
float amount = principal * pow((1 + ((interest_rate / 100) /times_compounded)), times_compounded);
```

Now for the precision, you can use `std::fixed` in conjunction with `std::setprecision` to set the default floating point printing precision when using `std::cout`. We can use a macro to make it more readable, like:

```
#define FIXED_FLOAT(x, p) std::fixed<<std::setprecision(p)<<(x)
```

So, the full output section would look like:

```
cout << "Interest Rate: " << setw(19) << FIXED_FLOAT(interest_rate, 2) << "%" << endl;
cout << "Times Compounded: " << setw(17) << FIXED_FLOAT(times_compounded, 0) << endl;
cout << "Principal: " << setw(17) << "$ " << setw(7) << FIXED_FLOAT(principal, 2) << endl;
cout << "Interest: " << setw(20) << "$ " << FIXED_FLOAT(interest, 2) << endl;
cout << "Amount in Savings: " << setw(9) << "$ " << FIXED_FLOAT(amount, 2);
```

Also, that `interest = interest_rate * 10.197647` seems fishy. Interest should just be the amount minus the principal.

Comment: Thank you Toribio, your suggestions solved all of my problems. :)